# How to address a Snakemake error at the stage of DAG computation?

Tags: memory, snakemake, directed-acyclic-graphs

I'm running in to an error with my Snakemake variant identification pipeline, when the original DAG of jobs is built. I believe this is a memory issue; when I test with a short list of input files, the DAG is constructed without issue, however, when I try with 300+ input paired-fastq, I receive the following error:

```
Building DAG of jobs...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home//.conda/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.6/site-packages/snakemake/__init__.py", line 633, in snakemake
    keepincomplete=keep_incomplete,
  File "/home//.conda/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.6/site-packages/snakemake/workflow.py", line 568, in execute
    dag.check_incomplete()
  File "/home//.conda/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.6/site-packages/snakemake/dag.py", line 281, in check_incomplete
    incomplete = self.incomplete_files
  File "/home//.conda/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.6/site-packages/snakemake/dag.py", line 402, in incomplete_files
    filterfalse(self.needrun, self.jobs),
  File "/home/k/.conda/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.6/site-packages/snakemake/dag.py", line 399, in <genexpr>
    job.output
  File "/home//.conda/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.6/site-packages/snakemake/persistence.py", line 205, in incomplete
    return any(map(lambda f: f.exists and marked_incomplete(f), job.output))
  File "/home//.conda/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.6/site-packages/snakemake/persistence.py", line 205, in <lambda>
    return any(map(lambda f: f.exists and marked_incomplete(f), job.output))
  File "/home//.conda/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.6/site-packages/snakemake/persistence.py", line 203, in marked_incomplete
    return self._read_record(self._metadata_path, f).get("incomplete", False)
  File "/home//.conda/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.6/site-packages/snakemake/persistence.py", line 322, in _read_record_cached
    return self._read_record_uncached(subject, id)
  File "/home//.conda/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.6/site-packages/snakemake/persistence.py", line 328, in _read_record_uncached
    return json.load(f)
  File "/home//.conda/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 299, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
  File "/home//.conda/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/home//.conda/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/home//.conda/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I'm not sure how to resolve this - if this is a known bug or if there is a way to define my pipeline to build a less complex DAG? I am including the first section of my Snakemake file as well. I use the rule all to define all desired output files.

```
################################
#### Mtb bwa/GATK Snakemake ####
################################
import numpy as np
from collections import defaultdict
import pandas as pd

samples_df = pd.read_table('config/tgen_samples2a.tsv',sep = ',').set_index("sample", drop=False)
sample_names = list(samples_df['sample'])
batch_names = list(samples_df['batch'])
#print(sample_names)

# fastq1 input function definition
def fq1_from_sample(wildcards):
  return samples_df.loc[wildcards.sample, "fastq_1"]

# fastq2 input function definition
def fq2_from_sample(wildcards):
  return samples_df.loc[wildcards.sample, "fastq_2"]

# Define config file. Stores sample names and other things.
configfile: "config/config.yaml"
  
# Define a rule for running the complete pipeline. 
rule all:
  wildcard_constraints:
      batch="IS-.+"
  input:
    trim = expand(['results/{batch}/{samp}/trim/{samp}_trim_1.fq.gz'], zip, samp=sample_names,batch=batch_names),
    kraken=expand('results/{batch}/{samp}/kraken/{samp}_trim_kr_1.fq.gz', zip, samp=sample_names,batch=batch_names),
    bams=expand('results/{batch}/{samp}/bams/{samp}_{mapper}_{ref}_sorted.bam', zip, samp=sample_names,batch=batch_names, ref = config['ref']*len(sample_names), mapper = config['mapper']*len(sample_names)), # When using zip, need to use vectors of equal lengths for all wildcards.
    per_samp_run_stats = expand('results/{batch}/{samp}/stats/{samp}_{mapper}_{ref}_combined_stats.csv', zip, samp=sample_names,batch=batch_names, ref = config['ref']*len(sample_names), mapper = config['mapper']*len(sample_names)),         
    amr_stats=expand('results/{batch}/{samp}/stats/{samp}_{mapper}_{ref}_amr.csv', samp=sample_names,batch=batch_names, ref=config['ref'], mapper=config['mapper']),
    cov_stats=expand('results/{batch}/{samp}/stats/{samp}_{mapper}_{ref}_cov_stats.txt', samp=sample_names,batch=batch_names, ref=config['ref'], mapper=config['mapper']),
    all_sample_stats=expand('results/{batch}/stats/combined_per_run_sample_stats.csv',batch = batch_names),
    vcfs=expand('results/{batch}/{samp}/vars/{samp}_{mapper}_{ref}_{caller}_qfilt.vcf.gz', samp=sample_names,batch=batch_names, ref=config['ref'], mapper=config['mapper'], caller = config['caller']),
    ann_vcfs=expand('results/{batch}/{samp}/vars/{samp}_{mapper}_{ref}_gatk_ann.vcf.gz', samp=sample_names,batch=batch_names, ref=config['ref'], mapper=config['mapper'], caller = config['caller']),
    fastas=expand('results/{batch}/{samp}/fasta/{samp}_{mapper}_{ref}_{caller}_{filter}.fa', samp=sample_names,batch=batch_names, ref=config['ref'], mapper=config['mapper'], caller = config['caller'], filter=config['filter']),
    profiles=expand('results/{batch}/{samp}/stats/{samp}_{mapper}_{ref}_lineage.csv', samp=sample_names,batch=batch_names, ref=config['ref'], mapper=config['mapper'])
               
# Trim reads for quality. 
rule trim_reads:  
  input: 
    p1=fq1_from_sample,
    p2=fq2_from_sample
  output:     
    trim1='results/{batch}/{sample}/trim/{sample}_trim_1.fq.gz',
    trim2='results/{batch}/{sample}/trim/{sample}_trim_2.fq.gz'
  log: 
    'results/{batch}/{sample}/trim/{sample}_trim_reads.log'
  shell:
    '{config[scripts_dir]}trim_reads.sh {input.p1} {input.p2} {output.trim1} {output.trim2} &>> {log}'

# Filter reads taxonomically with Kraken.   
rule taxonomic_filter:
  input:
    trim1='results/{batch}/{samp}/trim/{samp}_trim_1.fq.gz',
    trim2='results/{batch}/{samp}/trim/{samp}_trim_2.fq.gz'
  output: 
    kr1='results/{batch}/{samp}/kraken/{samp}_trim_kr_1.fq.gz',
    kr2='results/{batch}/{samp}/kraken/{samp}_trim_kr_2.fq.gz',
    kraken_report='results/{batch}/{samp}/kraken/{samp}_kraken.report',
    kraken_stats = 'results/{batch}/{samp}/kraken/{samp}_kraken_stats.csv'
  log: 
    'results/{batch}/{samp}/kraken/{samp}_kraken.log'
  threads: 8
  shell:
    '{config[scripts_dir]}run_kraken.sh {input.trim1} {input.trim2} {output.kr1} {output.kr2} {output.kraken_report} &>> {log}'
```

Thank you in advance for help using Snakemake!

All the best,

Comment: How are you invoking snakemake (i.e. what options)?  I'm seeing persistence and metadata stuff in your traceback.  You could try deleting the .snakemake directory to clear all your metadata.

Comment: Thank you Troy! I was invoking snakemake from the command line directly: ```snakemake -np``` to get the above error. Deleting the .snakemake directory solved my issue! Thank you! Is there a way to avoid this metadata issue in the future?

Comment: @TroyComi or ksw you could your comments into an answer since it appears it they solved the issue.

Comment: It seems related to this recent issue others are tagging [here](https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/issues/1342). I had seen it come up [here](https://www.biostars.org/p/9510221/#9510221).

Comment: In addition to what @Wayne posted, you need to be cautious with stopping snakemake through a kill signal or timeout which can prevent it from cleaning up properly.  If it is a concurrency issue you may just need to wait for a fix!

Answer (score 0):

I kind of doubt memory is an issue. 300+ is not much, especially if each of them is processed independently of the others.

Try to start from the subset of samples that you say worked and gradually increase it until you see the problem appearing. Perhaps you have some funny value in your sample sheet or in your `config`? `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)` hints at something like that in my impression.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was from @TroyComi, above: after deleting the .snakemake directory, the issue was resolved. Thank you!